# Click events are not fired on SVG elements in browser on touch enabled windows laptops

Tags: jquery, angularjs, svg, kendo-ui

I have a flow diagram implemented with AngularJS(1.3) and Kendo-UI(2016.1.112), and jquery (2.1.4). Every shape inside the flow diagram has a click event associated, which opens a pop-up

Everything works as expected, but on touch-enabled windows laptops pop-up does not open (Click event is never delivered), no errors in console. Most likely, issue is with touch events interfering with click event.

One workaround is to disable the touch input on the machine, which resolves the issue.

In HTML:

```
    <div kendo-diagram k-options="vm.options" k-data-source="vm.shapes" k-connections-data-source="vm.connections"
        ng-style="{'height': vm.height, 'width': vm.width}"></div>
```

I have the list of objects for shapes and connections.

In Controller:

```
var clicked = function (e) {
        alert("Hi");
        //...
};

vm.options = {
    shapeDefaults: {
        editable: false,
        visual: visualTemplate
    },
    click: clicked,
    pannable: false,
    dataBound: onDataBound,
    editable: false,
    zoom: 0.75,
    zoomStart: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    },
    drag: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    },
    connectionDefaults: {
        stroke: {
            color: "Black",
            width: 6
        },
        selectable: false,
        editable: false,
        endCap: {
            type: "ArrowEnd",
            stroke: {
                color: "Black",
                width: 6
            }
        }
    },
    layout: {
        type: "layered",
        subtype: "right",
        layerSeparation: 100,
        grid: {
            offsetX: 400,
            offsetY: 100
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Adding the code for the event handler will help people answer your question!

Comment: Have you tried using the [jQuery Mobile tap events](https://api.jquerymobile.com/category/events/)? A demo of how to integrate with Kendo/Angular [also available](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/touchevents/angular).

Comment: @Sandman My primary use case is to support click event, not particularly worried about supporting touch/tap events as the users are primarily desktop users.

Comment: [`tap`](https://api.jquerymobile.com/tap/) will support both!!

Comment: Just an update, have not found any solution to the problem, but the issue seems only happening in microsoft surface laptops but works on other devices (works on iPhone/iPad).

Answer (score 0):

Its the problem with old Kendo UI version (2016.1.112). Works after upgrading to 2016.2.504.